# Implementing simple scoring function with permutation test in R

Tags: r

I'm new in R, and I want to calculate some specific score for bunch of genes in biology.
can somebody help me to implement this ? :-)

I have following two vectors:

```
vector 1: (0.01,0.02,0.04,0.5,0.9,0.002,0.07,0.008)
vector 2: (1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
```

`vector 2` shows the membership of `vector 1` elements in specific set **c**

I want to implement a scoring function which would do the following steps :

1) takes `vector 1` and `vector 2` as inputs.

2) sort the `vector 1` with decreasing values and then sort the `vector 2`  with corresponding `vector 1`

3) it's go through the sorted `vector 1` and if for the element `i` of the `vector 1` the corresponding element of sorted `vector 2` is **1**, then the score should be increased by `(m-l)`,
else it should be decreased by `l` .

m= length of `vector 1`

l= # of non-zero elements in  `vector 2`

4) finally do the permutation on the `vectors 1` and `vector 2` and re-calculate the score of step 3. the permutation should preserve the true membership of `vector 1` element in `vector 2` . for example : `vector 1`: (10,7,4), `vector 2`: (0,0,1), after one possible permutation : `vector 1`: (4,7,10), `vector2`: (1,0,0)

here is my attempt :

```
            vector1<- c(0.01,0.02,0.04,0.5,0.9,0.002,0.07,0.008)

            vector2<- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

            m<-length(vector1)
            l<-nnzero(vector2, na.counted = NA)
            score=0

        score_function<-function (a,b){

            a<-sort(a,decreasing = T)

       for (i in a){
        if (b[i]==1) {
         score= + m-1
        } else{ score= score-l }
        }
score
        }
```

but I couldn't sort the  `b` (vector 2) according to `vector 1` (a)

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried for this? Several of these steps are elementary (like sorting) and we need to know what level you're at with this.

Comment: Additionally, you don't seem to accept answers on very many of your questions. It's an important part of this site to accept answers that solve your questions.

Comment: I used sort function to sort the vector 1, but I couldn't figure out how to sort vector 2  together with vector 1 .

Comment: I didn't know it, I should accept it the answers

Comment: So you don't know how to use `c()` to concatenate vectors?

Comment: but concatenation doesn't work here

Comment: The phrase "doesn't work" is pretty much useless in conveying what you intended or what you did.

Comment: What @DWin is saying is that you need to actually show us the code that didn't work.

Comment: @josilber, I added my attempt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by another vector use `order()` as an index to "[":

```
> vector1<- c(0.01,0.02,0.04,0.5,0.9,0.002,0.07,0.008)
> 
>             vector2<- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
> vector2[ order(vector1) ]
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: There is no "this" there.

Comment: `sort(vector1, decreasing=T)
[1] 0.900 0.500 0.070 0.040 0.020 0.010 0.008 0.002

>sorted_vector2:
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0`